# how iPhone 4/5/6 uses common images "@2x"

Tags: ios, iphone, image

I am new in using ios so i came across with one issue.

when I am using images of @2x for iPhone 5s and iPhone 6 then after executing i checked image size which is different in iPhone 6 may be due to its dimension then how would it be resizing the image up to which extent because iPhone 6 specification says that it is using @2x images.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone 6 uses 326 PPI screen which is same as iPhone 5S and previous Phones whereas iPhone 6 plus uses 401 PPI screen so it needs @3x images , read more [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

iPhone 6 might have different resolution but has same density of per pixel inch (PPI)

- **Resolution** concerns an absolute number of pixels.
- **Density** (aka Pixels per inch - PPI) concerns a relative number of pixels per inch which is same in case of iPhone 6 and previous iPhones , but different in iPhone 6 plus.

Check more about this [here in this  thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518852/android-what-is-the-difference-between-resolution-and-density)

Hence iPhone 6 uses @2x image same as  iPhones 4 , 5 and 5S.

Comment: __iPhone 6s?__ really?

Comment: Oops!!! slip of tongue :) Thanks

Comment: @Bhumit then when i am measuring size of an image in iPhone 6 simulator appears different then iPhone 5s simulator

Comment: @Bhumit thank you.. :) your answer cleared my doubt

Comment: Glad i could help, Please check the tick mark and accept the answer .

Comment: @Bhumit iPhone 6 having resolution 750*1334 so image size appears little bit big compared to image size in iphone 5s simulator? but ppi value remains same

Comment: Yes as it has higher resolution it will be bigger.