# Asset catalog images of type Retina 4 2x not presented on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, iphone-6, asset-catalog

I am using Asset Catalog that includes images of both: 2x, Retina 4 2x and 3x. All of those files are used in the correct devices iPhone 4, 4s => 2x, iPhone 5, 5s => Retina 4 2x, iPhone 6+ => 3x , but iPhone 6 which uses the 2x instead of the Retina 4 2x.
Has anyone encountered that issue?

Thanks

[Edited text]
The image set is a general image and not a launch screen. No matter whether I use universal or device settings, and no matter if I choose that the 2x Retina 4 is 1334 or 1136, the image presented on iPhone 6 is the one of the regular 2x.

I am adding screen shots of the three different settings I chose and for all three the result was the screen shot of the attached simulator

---------------**Screen Shot of Simulator (iPhone 6):**---------------

[image: Simulator]

---------------**Screen shot of settings with Device including 568:**---------------

[image: Device with 568]

---------------**Screen shot of settings with Device including 667**---------------

[image: Device with 667]

---------------**Screen shot of settings with Universal**---------------
[image: Universal]

---------------**Screen shot of settings of the image set (device settings & 667 height image)**---------------
[image]

---------------**Screen shot of the launch pad**----------------
[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your asset catalog, your question isn't very clear and it might help.

Comment: Are you talking about launch images, app icons, or a general image?

Comment: I answered your questions by editing the original question

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to resolve it and load the correct image (the Retina 4 one) for iPhone 6?

Comment: Not yet, I invested many hours on this, seems like a tough one. I would be happy to learn if you find a solution by any chance.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, it seems you want to display a full screen image in native resolution.

Yeah I think this might be a known issue. I don't think you can do it with an asset catalog. I ended up doing it like this guy here: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/25892207/342756](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892207/how-to-specify-size-for-iphone-6-customised-edge-to-edge-image)

My app is landscape, mnd my background image which fills the entire screen in native res I just call like this:

[UIImage imageForDeviceWithName:@"myBackground"];

And here is the list of files and resolutions for "myBackground" (again landscape):

- myBackground@2x.png == 960 × 640
- myBackground-568h@2x.png == 1136 × 640
- myBackground-667h@2x.png == 1334 × 750
- myBackground@3x.png == 2208 × 1242
- myBackground~ipad.png == 1024 × 768
- myBackground@2x~ipad.png == 2048 × 1536

I no longer support 1x. This pretty much covers all iOS 7 and iOS 8 devices. Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: This solution also works well with xcode7 which totally removed retina4 assets (why?? is there another way). It is by default loading @2x images which match iphone4 and 4s rather than images for the taller devices. I am referring to fullscreen images like background (not launch images)

Answer (score 1):

This works in Xcode v7.3 and verified in iPhone 4s simulator running iOS v9.3.

To avoid scaling issues, I did the following:

In my Images.xcassets, I created two Images Sets:

intro_screen

intro_screen_4

In the intro_screen I included the following images

1x 320x480

2x 750x1334

3x 1242x2208

In the intro_screen_4 I included only the image for iPhone 4

2x 640x960

In my code, I did the following:

```
int screenHeight = [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height;

if(screenHeight == 480)
{
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"intro_screen_4" ];
}
else {
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"intro_screen" ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue with device-specific settings in the asset catalog. Use the Universal settings instead (1x, 2x, and 3x). The iPhone 5, 5s, and 6 will then all use the 2x and all will be well.

Comment: Thanks, but I also tried that, but the result is the same

Comment: Let me ask you this: did you remember to create a dedicated iPhone 6 launch image (or use a launch image xib/storyboard)? Because if you didn't, your app is being scaled up on the iPhone 6 and is being treated as if this were a different device.

Comment: Yes, I've just added a screen shot of that in the original message

Comment: But what I'm thinking is, maybe you have to use a launch file (xib) _too_. [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html): "You use a launch XIB or storyboard file to indicate that your app runs on iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6." So maybe it isn't running _natively_ on the iPhone 6 until you do that.