# Creating a universal app or separate app for Ipad

Tags: objective-c, resize, ios-universal-app, widescreen

I have a game made in sprite kit, xcode 5 flappy bird type game. But it is only for iphone. I want to make it for iPad to but dont know how to I made images for all Ipads and iphone and now I need to make separate app for iPad. Can I create new app with the same name but make it for iPad only and distribute it to App Store? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  Go into your project, in the menu up top select file/new target to make an iPad app in the same project and easily include many / most of the same classes.  You can have the same display name (but different bundle ID) but most developers would probably append the name with ~pro or ~HD or something like that in order that differentiate the two products.  They would probably also shift the colour scheme on the icon a little.  Remember its possible that iPad users may have your original iPhone app on their iPad despite thats its an iPhone app, so they might end up with the same icon and bundle display name twice on their iPad springboard, which Im sure you'll agree would be undesirable.

You can also make your existing app into a 'universal' app with an update, so it runs natively on iPad rather than scaling up, this is what I would probably do but each to their own, there are many business models.  I personally think with all different sized phone models we have to support these days ( 4! ) adding the iPad (which despite different form factors is still only one real 'size' ) is pretty trivial.

Comment: Can I do it in all xcodes for example xcode 6.1? And do I have to add special code like if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
{
        // Place iPhone/iPod specific code here...
} else {
        // Place iPad-specific code here...
} or I just create new storyboard, viewController.h.m and MySccene.h.m? Please tell me? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes you totally can do this, choose a xib or storyboard file name based on device type for example.  I believe that the USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() stuff has been deprecated as of iOs8 however, the lines between tablet and phone have really been blurred now so that kind of makes sense.  See my response to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892207/how-to-specify-size-for-iphone-6-customised-edge-to-edge-image/26684508#26684508 for a kind of replacement, note the NSString method in the UIImage category there, you could easily modify that to make a nib file name for example..

Comment: Just like I said Thanks in advance for replaying. Now let me read you comment :).