# Images.xcassets taking wrong image for the iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have set the three image for the @2x @Retina 4 and @3x.

[image]

When i run the app i got the following result.

1. `iPhone 4s` : twitter image
2. `iPhone 5` : Google image
3. `iPhone 6+` : facebook image.
4. `iPhone 6`  : twitter image

everything is good. but when I run on the **iPhone 6** its taking the **twitter** image but it should take the **google** image.

Is this bug of xcode?

Comment: Why would the iPhone 6 use the iPhone 5 image? "Retina 4 2x" is for 4" devices.

Comment: @rmaddy See this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: Ok fine iPhone 6 not take the iPhone 5 image. but why its taking the iPhone 4s image @rmaddy

Comment: Because the iPhone 6 (not the 6+) uses `@2x` images.

Comment: but iPhone 5 is also uses the @2x images..

Comment: Yes, but the iPhone 5 is a 4" device. Since you provided an image specific to 4" devices, the iPhone 5 uses it. The iPhone 6 is not a 4" device.

Comment: @Yasika That chart doesn't apply here.

Comment: @SidShah Why are you trying to use different icons on different devices?

Comment: because i have different size for all the device. I have followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020979/xcode-6-xcassets-for-universal-image-support.

Comment: do you know any other way..?

Comment: @SidShah : I have faced the same problem, then I have managed this using codebase, find the similar code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892207/how-to-specify-size-for-iphone-6-customised-edge-to-edge-image?lq=1

Comment: Drop R4, use 2x, 3x. Set up large enough icons and scale them with autolayout

Comment: @Andy can you share some logic for the scale.

Comment: Drop Image view, size them, set aspect ratio constraints, set other constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ridiculous from apple.

There is no any specific place where you can put the iPhone 6 images. you have to do with the condition.

Comment: It is ridiculous! Because 1334/750 is about 1.778, which is close to 1136/640 = 1.775 while 960/640 = 1.5. My 640*1136 pictures do show properly on iPhone 6 while 640*960 pictures are distorted.

Answer (score 2):

In iPhone 6 you will get the image which is of @2x
In iPhone 5 and 5s you will get the image of Retina 4 @2x.

Check this example image I have set here.
[image]

Result in iPhone 5

[image]

Result in iPhone 6

[image]

but in iPhone 4 and iPhone 6 you will get same image. For this time you have to code for different devices. Because apple does not provide the document for it. by the time if I got something new then I will post here.

Thanks!

Comment: Then how will i seperate for the iPhone 3.5 inch screen stuff and 6 stuff

Comment: What do you mean by 3.5 inch!! 1x image is for iphone 4s and 4

Comment: Oh! I got your point Retina 4 @2x image is for iPhone 4s. Sorry

Comment: This is ridiculous from apple. I want to show a different sized image of tutorials in iphone 4 and iphone 6...