# Image assets not working correct in iOS [Big issue]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, uiimageasset

I used image asset for Image management in my app. My app supports iPhone4,iPhone5 & iPhone6, iPhone6 plus devices.

but when I uses image assets then **what resolution need for @2x image by which both iPhone4 & iphone6 works?**

**My try for view background image**

[image]

**Case 1** if I put 640 X 960 resolution image for @2x then works fine for iPhone4 but not works in iPhone6.

**Case 2** if I put 750 X 1334 resolution image for @2x then works fine for iPhone6 but not works in iPhone4.

**Help me to solve this**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem with me [Images.xcassets taking wrong image for the iPhone 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577082/images-xcassets-taking-wrong-image-for-the-iphone-6).

There is no any specific place where you can put the iPhone 6 images. you have to do with the condition.

Comment: Thanks for reply... but are you sure about this?
because I can not still imagine this kind of big mistake by apple.

Comment: iPhone 4s ,5 , 6 takes the @2x images.. and we have only 2 place one for 4s and other is Retina 4 2x.. so no other way

Comment: I am just waiting for others answer also. If I don't find any other good solution then I will accept your answer don't worry. just satisfy with +1 rightnow

Comment: but what a bug it this from apple, isn't it?