# SpriteKit SKScene size for iPhone 5, 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I'm trying to build an app using SpriteKit for iPhone 5,6, and 6 plus.  I have created a background image for each resolution:

```
image-1.png    // of size 1136 x 640, for iPhone 5
image-1@x2.png // of size 1334 x 750, for iPhone 6
image-1@x3.png // of size 2208 x 1242, for iPhone 6 plus
```

In Xcode 7, when I run my code on the simulator for iPhone 6 and 6 plus the correct and corresponding image is automatically picked.  But when I run the code for iPhone 5 the iPhone 6 image is picked (image-1@x2.png) and not the correct image (image-1.png).  Why?

In SKScene.didMoveToView() I set the scene size to the view's frame size:

```
self.size = view.frame.size
```

When I add the image to the scene I do:

```
self.addChild(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"image-1"))
```

If I use "image-1.png", I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such place specially for iPhone 5 and 6. they both take @2x images. So in both device it will pick @2x images.

You need to set programmatically or on based condition.

Refer to my old question : [Images.xcassets taking wrong image for the iPhone 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577082/images-xcassets-taking-wrong-image-for-the-iphone-6)

Comment: Dang it!  You're right!  I wish there was a solution that Apple could provide that is simple.  I've decided to create my own system for my own needs: I'll suffix each image name with -5,-6,-6p for now and do my own name resolution.