# Image.xcassets specify image for iPhone 6

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6.1, xcasset

I have tested iPhone 6 and seems when I have set 1x 2x Retina4 2x and 3x images the iPhone 6 uses 2x image that is 640 x 960 px image.

How can I set image for iPhone 6 which needs 750×1334 px?

Comment: Have you set *Launch Screen File* at General Settings?

Comment: @Brain89 sure of course

Comment: @Brain89, in any case I don't see options for the iPhone 6 in assets

Comment: iPhone 6 options are Retina HD 4.7 or 2x scale factor. See this [link](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified). Also check this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added)

Comment: Answer on your question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892207/how-to-specify-size-for-iphone-6-customised-edge-to-edge-image)

Comment: may help this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781422/image-resolution-for-new-iphone-6-and-6-3x-support-added/25783648#25783648

Answer (score -2):

```
1x image = 640 x 960 pixel image

2x image = 750 x 1334 pixel image

3x image = 1242 x 2208 pixel image
```

I think the solution is updating your 2x image to 750x1334 px, because iPhone 6 will use the 2x image.

From **iOS Human Interface Guidelines**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Iconography.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH59-SW1

> Support the Retina display. Make sure that you supply high resolution assets for all artwork and graphics in your app. In particular, supply @3x assets for iPhone 6 Plus and @2x assets for all other high-resolution iOS devices.

Comment: I supposed that 1x is for 320 x 480? is not it?

Comment: 1x is 320 x 480 points, which is 640 x 960 pixels. 1 point is 2 pixels on Retina devices(except iPhone 6 plus, where 1 point is 3 pixels. Please see the **Points Versus Pixels** section in the Apple document [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)
Or [this one](http://beageek.biz/points-vs-pixels-in-ios/) which has pictures to illustrate the idea.

Comment: I have found this info: Original iPhone - without retina display. Scaling factor is 1.
iPhone 5 - with Retina display, scaling factor is 2.
iPhone 6 Plus - with Retina display HD. Scaling factor is 3 and the image is afterwards downscaled from rendered 2208 × 1242 pixels to 1920 × 1080 pixels.