# iOS @2x images conflicting

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, hig, human-interface

I've a little confusion and facing a little problem regarding `@2x` images in `iOS` as according to `Human Interface Guidelines HIG`, the `@2x` For `iPhone 6: 750 x 1334 (@2x)` for portrait but same `@2x` for `iPhone 4S` has size of `640x1136`.

[HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)

When I placed @2x image named as `MyTestImage@2x.png` of size `750 x 1134`, it was fine for `iPhone 6` but not for `iPhone 4S`, but if I put `MyTestImage@2x.png` of size `640x1136` then its fine for `iPhone 4S` but not for i`Phone 6`.

I also placed `640x1136` as `Retina 4 2x` named as `MyTestImage-568h@2x.png` but its also not working for me.

Whats I'm conflicting? What should be the actual image sizes of @2x for iPhone 4S and iPhone 6 if I talk about a full screen image.
And also what should be the correct retina display image size.

**EDIT 1:**
My question is different as I want to know the difference between @2x and -568h@2x retina display regarding both screens. Also, any optimal solution for this which can avoid image redundancies.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does iPhone 6 use @2x image assets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871033/why-does-iphone-6-use-2x-image-assets)